# Using VLOOKUP with merge in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas DataFrame with almost 540000 rows:

```
df1.head()

    username  hour    totalCount
0   lowi      00:00   12
1   klark     00:00   0
2   sturi     00:00   2
3   nukr      00:00   10
4   irore     00:00   2
```

I also have this other pandas DataFrame with almost 52000 rows and with some duplicated rows:

```
df2.head()

   username   community
0    klark       0
1    irore       2
2    sturi       2
3    sturi       2
4    sturi       2
```

I want to merge the column of 'community' of df2 into the df1, but in the corresponding row according to the username.
I have used this code:

```
df_merge = df_hu.merge(df_comm, on='username')
df_merge
```

But I get the following DataFrame with almost 1205880 rows and duplicated ones:

```
    username    hour    totalCount  community
0   lowi        00:00   12          2
1   lowi        00:00   12          2
2   lowi        00:00   12          2
3   lowi        01:00   9           2
4   lowi        01:00   9           2
```

The expected output would be this:

```
df_merge.head()

    username  hour    totalCount community
0   lowi      00:00   12         2
1   klark     00:00   0          0
2   sturi     00:00   2          2
3   nukr      00:00   10         1 (not showed in the example)
4   irore     00:00   2          1 (not showed in the example)
```

Comment: Assuming there is only one `community` per `username`: `df_hu.merge(df_comm.drop_duplicates(), on='username', how='left')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates().set_index('username')
df1['community'] = df1['username'].map(df2['community'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  username   hour  totalCount  community
0     lowi  00:00          12        NaN
1    klark  00:00           0        0.0
2    sturi  00:00           2        2.0
3     nukr  00:00          10        NaN
4    irore  00:00           2        2.0
```

Note that `lowi` and `nukr` weren't in the example `df2` so `NaN`.

Comment: May I know why didn't you use `merge` instead of `map`. because I think `merge` is efficient than `map`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Used `map` since it ran about 1.5x faster than `merge` in my environment.

Comment: Yes, map is faster than merge for such usecases. :) @MohamedThasinah